# Unable to publish Google editor add-on to the G Suite Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-console-developer, google-apps-script-addon, google-slides

Currently, I'm working on a project that will be sharing a written in Apps-Script framework Google Slides extensions. One of the first tasks I've had to do was how to publish an example add-on to a whole private domain? To accomplish this I've used the instruction from official Google documentation:

[Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons)

I've gone through these steps without any bigger problems, but it looks like not everything has gone as expected. My extension now is visible in a Chrome Web Store, but unfortunately not in G Suite Marketplace. In result, I cannot see it in a list of add-ons in Google Slides editor that are available for my private domain.

I've published script to Chrome Web Store and also enabled and configured G Suite Marketplace SDK in my project. And even the state of publishing looks fine:

[image: Web Store Developer Dashboard]
[image: G Suite Marketplace Configuration]

My manifest.json file

[image: manifest.json]

It even looks like my extension is installed for a whole domain(I've clicked 'Integrate with Google' button)

[image: Admin Marketplace]

But still I cannot see my add-on in Google Slides as well as in G Suite Marketplace:

[image: Add-ons for a private domain in G Suite Marketplace]
[image: Domain add-ons in Google Slides]

Did somebody ever faced a similar situation? Did I skipped something important or am I doing something in a wrong way?

Comment: A Chrome browser extension and an Editor Add-on are two different things.  Do not upload a manifest file for an Editor Add-on.  That won't work.  To publish an Editor Add-on you must do it through the Apps Script editor, and the Apps Script editor automatically creates the manifest file.  I'm not sure if you can fix the issue without creating a new Apps Script file and starting over again.  If you have enabled APIs for the Apps Script project, then you may want to create a "standard" Google Cloud Project to associate with the Apps Script project.

Comment: When did you build the add-on? becaus eif you check again in the link you provided ([here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons)) you'll see a message that says **Warning: Originally editor add-ons were published to the Chrome Web Store, and could optionally be published in the G Suite Marketplace to make them domain-wide installable.

Publishing to the G Suite Marketplace is no longer optional. The publishing instructions below have been revised to reflect this. See Chrome Web Store migration for more details.**

Comment: @AlanWells When I click 'Deploy as docs add-on' from Apps-Script project then only appears a pop-up that allows me to publish my app in Chrome Web Store and in addidtion I have an option to publish it also in G Suite Marketplace(option is checked but disabled so I can't unckeck it even if I wanted). I have enabled the G Suite Marketplace SDK and the whole configuration process succeed. Do I need to enable some another API in Google Console ?

Comment: @AlbertoMolina Yes, I've seen such a message in Google Web Store Dashboard and I've done those instructions succesfully but the problem is that still I can't see my app in G Suite Marketplace.

Comment: @KacperNitubydz Have you seen [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/domain-wide-web-app) example, I know you are not doing a web app, but some of the process seems quite similar to what you are doing.

Comment: The scopes need to be added in at least 2 different places, and if you add scopes to the appsscript.json file, then the scopes need to be in 3 places.  The scopes must be listed in "APIs and Services -> Credentials ->OAuth consent screen"  **AND** the scopes must be listed in the "GSuite Marketplace Configuration"  And they need to be exactly the same.  The json file that you are showing in your post is NOT what the appsscript.json file should look like.  If you uploaded a file for the manifest in the Chrome Web Store developer dashboard, then that is a problem.  And add-on is not an extension

Answer (score 0):

@AlanWells I've did what you said and saved configuration, but still I can't see my addon in domain-wide addons in Google Slides editor as well as in G Suite Marketplace.

[Required scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKZuU.png)

[Scopes in project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxjdQ.png)

[Scopes in Marketplace configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAdhS.png)

Can I do anything else in this situation ?